# jQuery перебор DOM элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Приветствую всех.
Есть html примерно такой структуры:

```
    <div class="title"></div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="title"></div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="item" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="item" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="item" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="title"></div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="item" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="item" style="display: none"></div>
</div>
```

Подскажите, как сделать блоки класса "title" тоже display: none , если все item внутри .block   display: none (как бы пустые) , а если хоть один видимый, то не трогать ?

Пробовал функцией .each() обходить .block , а внутри еще .each() по .item  ничего не выходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Извратиться что ли и упихать всё в одну конструкцию?
Хм.. А вообще я подумал... И что-то ничего лучше не придумывается...

```js
$(".title").hide().next().children(":visible").parent().prev().show()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="title">A</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="title">B</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="item" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="item" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="item" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="title">C</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="item" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="item" style="display: none"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Работает))) Я могу только посмеяться над собой и над потраченным временем)) Спасибо!

Comment: Вообще, тут принято принимать лучший ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него. Хотя, в данном случае можно и подождать - вдруг кто-то предложит что-то более правильное. Метку принятого ответа всегда можно переставить на другой, но вопросы без принятых ответов обычно получают больше внимания. Я сначала считал, что этот ответ не очень хороший, но потом что-то понял, что ничего лучше-то и не придумывается.

Comment: Нажал)) Еще раз спасибо.